# getting the argument names of a function like netbeans does

Tags: java, netbeans

Ok, this could be a tricky one. For a code generating tool I need to know methods and arguments of a class. The method name and argument types are the easy ones - just using reflection. But the argument name - and I need the real argument name - is a tricky one because this information is in the javadoc. In my case I use Netbeans 8 and I am pretty sure if Netbeans can get the arguments name I can too. Does anyone know how to read the javadoc to get the argument names of a method?

PS I know this question will pop up. I need the real argument names because the generated code provides an api and it is not very helpful for a developper to use an api where the api methods are something like set_a1, set_a2, and so on.

Comment: Indeed, this is tricky, and will involve a considerable effort. Unless... well, unless you can do it the Java8 way: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodparameterreflection.html

Comment: @Marco13 oh yes this is an option, I have just tried it out - works great. I would accept this as an answer if you would post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, this is tricky, and will involve a considerable effort if you intend to find a general solution that works for arbitrary (third-party) classes and arbitrary Java versions.

However, under certain conditions, there may be a simple solution:

**If** you can compile the classes on your onw, and **if** you can use Java 8, then you can use the [Method Parameter Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodparameterreflection.html) infrastructure that was added in Java 8. When compiling the classes with `javac -parameters ...`, then the parameter names are added to the class file, and can be obtained from the method by calling [getParameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Executable.html#getParameters--) on the `Method` object, and then [Parameter#getName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Parameter.html#getName--)

```
Parameter parameters[] = method.getParameters();
String name = parameters[0].getName();
...
```